# Angularjs: Unable to run the code

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller

I am new to angularjs and these are the files I have created.
I have tried my best but could not run the above code.

myApp(Folder)

```
- app.js
- controller.js
- index.html
- phone-detail.html
- phone-list.html
```

The Home page is the phone-list.html and when clicked on a phone routes to a phone-detail.html page.

app.js

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', ['ngMaterial','phonecatControllers','$routeProvider']);

phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {
        templateUrl: 'phone-detail.html',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/phones'
      });
  }]);
```

controller.js

```
var phonecatControllers = angular.module('phonecatControllers', []);
phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope',
function ($scope) {

$scope.phones = 
[{"Device":"ipad mini","Model":"MD528LL/A"},
{"Device":"ipadair","Model":"MD785LL/A"}]
}]);

phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
function($scope, $routeParams) {
$scope.Model = $routeParams.Model;
}]);
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp">
<head>

<!-- Angular Material CSS now available via Google CDN; version 0.10 used here -->

<!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.10.0/angular-material.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="controller.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div ng-view>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

phone-list.html

```
<div class="mainContent" style="margin:5%">

<li ng-repeat="phone in phones" style="float:left; margin:40px" >  

<md-content style="padding:0px; overflow-y: hidden">

<md-card style="width:300px; height:300px; margin:0px" > 

<img ng-src="{{phone.image}}" class="md-card-image" style="height:40%" alt="image caption" >

<md-card-content style="padding:0; height:25%">

<h6 class="md-title">{{phone.Device}}</h6> <hr style="opacity:0.5">

</md-card-content>

<md-card-footer class="md-actions" layout="row" layout-align="center" style="padding:0">

<md-button class="md-raised">Action 1</md-button>

<md-button class="md-raised">Action 2</md-button>

</md-card-footer>

</md-card>

</md-content>

</li>   

</div>
```

phone-detail.html

{{phone.Device}}

Comment: Did you look in the console log for errors?

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=phonecatApp&p1=Err…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)

Comment: This is what I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

You should inject `ngRoute` module instead of `$routeProvider` in :

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', ['ngMaterial','phonecatControllers','$routeProvider'])
```

Also make sure you included the sources of *angular-route.js* as angular routing is separated from angular sources.

**Edit:** From the *index.html* you posted I see you included *angular-route.js* but it appears you are missing the script of *angular-material*, so be sure to add :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.10.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What Michael said, but also removing ngMaterial gets rid of the error.

Comment: Maybe you forgot the *angular-material* ? In the home page I see you linked the css but no script

Comment: Edited the answer to add the missing *angular-material* script inclusion.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/rohitborade/Desktop/latest/phone-list.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: I mean ..I am not running it from a localhost. Just opening the index.html file in the browser. Is it ok to run that way.

Comment: Better test from a web server, as http templates are fetched by xhr. If you have python 3+ you can run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer {portNumber}`